# check inner join table existance

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

my tbl_module may consist on empty id, what i want to do is to perform a checking on it, but there are errors return to me, my query doesnt work

```
SET @IID = 1
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Module FROM tbl_user t1
```

my problem started here, i cannot begin to join my previous query,i know this is an illegal way of execute the query, but can someone correct me or enlighten me?

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT t2.ID FROM tbl_Module t2 where @IID = t2.id)
BEGIN
  INNER JOIN tbl_Module t2 where t1.id = t2.id
 END
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a left join rather then an inner join?

Comment: You've tagged this as SQL Server and MySQL... which one are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one (MS SQL) -

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = '
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.tbl_user t1
' + CASE WHEN OBJECT_ID('dbo.tbl_Module') IS NOT NULL 
        THEN 'JOIN dbo.tbl_Module t2 ON t1.id = t2.id' 
        ELSE ''
    END

PRINT @SQL
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Compare CASE and IF EXIST, which one is better in performance? =)

Comment: In your case `CASE` and `IF EXIST` are equal. For this query I prefer use `CASE + OBJECT_ID`.

Comment: I don't think this addresses the question.  The Q requires a matching ID in tbl_Module not the presence of the table itself (which would be *extremely* wrong)

Comment: When it comes to performance, I think you should go for the LEFT JOIN approach. SQL statements made by appending strings does often lead to bad performance.

Answer (score 1):

As Don said, it is more common to do a LEFT JOIN, which will just put NULL in the column t1.Module if no module with that id exists:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Module FROM tbl_user t1
LEFT JOIN tbl_Module t2 where t1.id = t2.id
```

But your requirements may be special?
Hope this helps!